# ¿Cómo puedo mostrar el resultado de una función en un <div> y no en un alert?

Tags: javascript, html5, funciones

Como puedo mostrar el resultado de la siguiente función en un `<div>` y no en un alert.

```
<script>
  function suma (a,b){
    var sum = a+b;
    alert(sum);
  };
  suma(3,4);
</script>
```

Comment: ... y para tomar el valor de `<div id="content"></div>` y pasarlo a una variable _PHP_, por ejemplo `$contenido`, ¿Cómo se haría?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Podrias usar el `getElementById` para asignar el valor de la suma

```js
  function suma (a,b){
    var sum = a + b;

    document.getElementById('resultado').innerHTML = sum;
  };

  suma(3,4);
```

```html
<div id="resultado"></div>
```

Answer (score 5):

Puedes ocupar **innerHTML** de javascript por ejemplo:

```html
<html>

<head></head>

<body>

    <div id="content"></div>


</body>
<script>
function suma (a,b){
    var sum = a+b;
    document.getElementById("content").innerHTML = sum;
  };
  suma(3,4);

</script>

</html>
```

Comment: Como pasar ese resultado <div id=content> </div> a una variable php